# How to make javascript remember a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, cookies

```
function name(){
var name = prompt("Vul hier uw naam in.");
if (name != null){
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = 
"Hallo " + name + ", welkom op onze website. 
Op deze website kunt u informatie vinden over het vak informatica.";
document.cookie="name";}}
```

I'm trying to find a way to make my web page remember the name variable so that users don't have to tell their name each time the open the web page. it's also supposed to use the same variable at other pages. For example: when you open the web page, you get a prompt to fill in your name. after that, you get a personalized welcome message. then, when you navigate to the next page, your name will still be used.

I'm very new to javascripts so please answer as simple as possible. Also, if you have some spare time, please explain to me how te code works. it will help me to understand javascripts better.

thanks for your time.

Comment: `localStorage` is so much better than cookies. Only use cookies if you *specifically* need them.

Comment: Alright, but could you then explain localstorage to me?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Comment: here is nice tutorial http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/11/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use localStorage. You can use localStorage.getItem('name') to get the name. If it doesn't exist yet, it will return null. And you can use localStorage.setItem('name', name) to set the name.

```
function getName() {
    var name;
    if(localStorage.getItem('name') === null) {
        name = prompt("Vul hier uw naam in.");
        localStorage.setItem('name', name);
    } else {
        name = localStorage.getItem('name');
    }
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML =
        "Hallo " + name + ", welkom op onze website. Op deze website kunt u informatie vinden over het vak informatica.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, `localStorage` is the way to go.
Here's a brief overview and how you might use it to do the task you describe.

Local storage provides you with up to 5MB of persistent storage on the client-side (i.e. on the computers of those people using your website). The basic syntax is as follows:

```
// is localStorage available?
if (typeof window.localStorage != 'undefined') {
    // store
    localStorage.setItem('hello', 'Hello World!');

    // retrieve
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('hello'));

    // delete
    localStorage.removeItem('hello');
}
```

Unlike cookies, the information stored in local storage is never transferred to the server, which makes it more performant. It is supported on a wide variety of browsers, as can be seen [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=namevalue-storage). If you do need to support older browsers, there are [polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-storage-localstorage-and-sessionstorage) available to make your life easier.

To remember a user's name you would place the following at the bottom of your web page (in script tags):

```
function greetUser() {
  var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
  if(!name){
    name = prompt("Vul hier uw naam in.");
    localStorage.setItem('name', name);
  }
  alert("Welcome, " + name);
}

greetUser();
```

Finally, when testing this, please be aware that some browsers, such as IE8, don’t support local storage with the `file://` protocol.